# Haskell: Given a list of numbers and a number k, return whether any two numbers from the list add up to k

Tags: haskell

Given a list of numbers and a number k, return whether any two numbers from the list add up to k.

For example, given [10, 15, 3, 7] and k of 17, return true since 10 + 7 is 17.

The program must prompt the user for input.

The program must accept the list as a collection of comma separated values.

The values should all be integers.

The input list can be between 1 and 42 number long.

What I have done

I have been able to input the list of integer as a list and seperated by commas but am not able to return true when 2 numbers add to k

```
toList :: String -> [Integer]
toList input = read ("[" ++ input ++ "]")

main = do
   putStrLn "Enter a list of numbers (separated by comma):"
   input <- getLine
   print $ k (toList input)
```

Comment: This is still a homework question, and you have not attempted to solve the problem.

Comment: See that code. Just 1 part missing from the question k of 17, return true since 10 + 7 is 17. Just that. Yes it is homework. I have done most of it already

Comment: The part that is missing is the main part.  And you did not attempt it.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is a homework question

Comment: So the problem is [in two parts](https://i.imgur.com/rCr9A.png) and you have done Part 1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are following approaches.

1) Create a list pf pairs which are all combinations [(10,10),(10,15),..,(15,10),(15,3)..]. 
Now you can use simple **any** function on this list to check if any pair add up to given number.

```
getCoupleList :: [a]->[(a,a)]
getCoupleList [] = []
getCoupleList [x] = []
getCoupleList (x:xs) = map (\y->(x,y)) xs ++ getCoupleList xs

getSumOfCoupleList :: Num a => [(a,a)]->[a]
getSumOfCoupleList xs = map (\x -> fst x + snd x) xs 

isSum :: [Int]->Int->Bool
isSum xs k = any (==k) $ (getSumOfCoupleList.getCoupleList) xs
```

or directly check wuthout getSumOfCoupleList

```
isSum xs k = any (\(a,b)-> a + b == k) $ (getSumOfCoupleList.getCoupleList) xs
```

If you check creating the couple list and finding the sum in not needed. We can directly get the list of sum with simple changes.

```
getSumList :: Num a=>[a]->[a]
getSumList [] = []
getSumList [x] = []
getSumList (x:xs) = map (+x) xs ++ getSumList xs

isSum1 :: [Int]->Int->Bool
isSum1 xs k = any (==k) $ getSumList xs
```

2) Create another list from given list by subtracting every element from 17. Now just check if any number from first list is present in second.

```
isSum2 :: [Int]->Int->Bool 
isSum2 xs k = let newList = map (k-) xs
                  intersectList = xs `intersect` newList
                  in not (null intersectList)
```

Answer (score 0):

It's a naive method, not optimized and just show an example.

```
toList :: String -> [Integer]
toList input = read ("[" ++ input ++ "]")



check :: Integer -> [Integer] -> Bool 
check k (x:xs) = if ((k-x) `elem` xs) 
         then True
         else (check k xs)
check k x = False 

main = do
let k = 12
 putStrLn "Enter a list of numbers (separated by comma):"
 input <- getLine
 print $  (check k  (toList input))
```

Answer (score 0):

I was recently asked the same exact question in an interview, here's one of my answer

```
import util
arr = [10, 15, 3, 8]
k = 17
for i in range(0, len(arr)):
    arr_new.append(abs(arr[i] -17))


res= list(set(arr).intersection(arr_new))

if (len(res)>0):
    print(str(res[0]) + " + " + str(res[1]) +"= "+ str(k ))
else:
    print("No numbers add up to k")
```